# What does it mean to move with silver feet?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

While reading Oscar Wilde's, The Picture of Dorian Gray, I came across this:

> There was a silence. The evening darkened in the room. Noiselessly and with **silver feet** the shadows crept in from the garden. The colours faded wearily out of things.

I tried searching for what it meant to move with silver feet but found only discussions of Bush having a silver foot in his mouth. On this site I found mentions of *clay feet*, but nothing of *silver feet*.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage! Perhaps it is a metaphor describing the color of the shadows at that particular hour...

Comment: May be a reference to "quicksilver" ie liquid metal (mercury), implying silence and smooth movement.

Comment: It's literary criticism. Interpret it how you like.

Comment: The light areas in the shadow patterns are silvery and move gradually as the moon rises..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Move with silver feet* is most likely a reference to quicksilver, which is another name for the liquid metal mercury. So, it's the movement of shadows being described here.

*Quicksilver* -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/quicksilver)

> (noun) 1.1 Used in similes and metaphors to describe something that moves or changes very quickly, or that is difficult to hold or contain.
>
> *His mood changed like quicksilver*
> *The achievement is palpable: the quicksilver movements of fish, the movement of water and the play of light through it, the interior of a whale's mouth.*

Comment: Excellent! I appreciate everybody pitching in to clear that up for me. Hopefully I can return the favor.

Comment: @SaucyDave you realize this is no more than speculation at this point. There is no evidence presented here of any connection.

Comment: How can anything creep very quickly?

Comment: @GregLee maybe they're like ninjas.